# Item Search implementation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing ASP.NET application with sql server 2012 database.
I would like have product search functionality similar search available in Amazon.com or target.com or any other online shopping site.

Could you please suggest how can I implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: I created key search column, which include major key words used to search a each item/record. but this results very slow with large set of items in the database

Answer (score 0):

Building a dictionary type search will be difficult, but simple free text searching would be a good start.

[Free Text Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)